# Line not drawn in Line chart with react-chartjs-2

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I try to draw multi line chart (single line doesn't work as well) using react-chartjs-2 `Line` component

**My data structure**

```
const data = {
    labels: dataFromDb.map(item => item.period),
    datasets: [
        {
            data: dataFromDb,
            backgroundColor: '#FAA46A',
            borderColor: '#FAA46A',
            label: i18n.sellPrice,
            parsing: { yAxisKey: 'price_so' },
        },
        {
            data: dataFromDb,
            backgroundColor: '#1DCF35',
            borderColor: '#1DCF35',
            label: i18n.purchasePrice,
            parsing: { yAxisKey: 'price_po' },
        },
    ],
};
```

Data from db is array of objects `{period: string, price_so: number, price_po: number, quantity: number}`

**My chart**

```
<Line
    height={400}
    data={data}
    options={{
        animation: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        elements: { line: { tension: 0.4 } },
        scales: {
            x: { grid: { display: false }, offset: true },
            y: {
                title: { text: i18n.amount, display: true },
                grid: { display: false },
            },
        },
    }}
/>
```

**Result**
[image]

Problem is that none of the lines Visible. I can see that data is read as y axis have values mapped by object properties `price_so` and `price_po` (900 is highest value for price_po in objects array from db) and legend recognized datasets as correct colors applied but lines not draw. Am I missing something in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also set `xAxisKey` in `parsing`. It seems logical that the library would use `period` since you defined the labels as such, but apparently it doesn't make that infferrence by itself.

Here's a non-react example based on your code, with invented data:

```js
const dataFromDb = [
    {period: '2019', price_so: 100, price_po: 110},
    {period: '2020', price_so: 120, price_po: 120},
    {period: '2021', price_so: 110, price_po: 109},
    {period: '2022', price_so: 90, price_po: 100},
    {period: '2023', price_so: 105, price_po: 115},
];
const data = {
    labels: dataFromDb.map(item => item.period),
    datasets: [
        {
            data: dataFromDb,
            backgroundColor: '#FAA46A',
            borderColor: '#FAA46A',
            label: 'sellPrice',
            parsing: { xAxisKey: 'period', yAxisKey: 'price_so' },
        },
        {
            data: dataFromDb,
            backgroundColor: '#1DCF35',
            borderColor: '#1DCF35',
            label: 'purchasePrice',
            parsing: { xAxisKey: 'period', yAxisKey: 'price_po' },
        },
    ],
};

const options={
    animation: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    /*elements: { line: { tension: 0.4 } },*/
    scales: {
        x: { grid: { display: false }, offset: true },
        y: {
            title: { text: 'amount', display: true },
            grid: { display: false },
        },
    },
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#line-chart'), {type:'line', data, options});
```

```html
<div id="line-chart-container">
<canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.2/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-t41WshQCxr9T3SWH3DBZoDnAT9gfVLtQS+NKO60fdAwScoB37rXtdxT/oKe986G0BFnP4mtGzXxuYpHrMoMJLA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</script>
```